# What is the best way to append a javascript variable/parameter parameter to MVC Url.Action inside the view?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, url.action

I'm generating a `url action` by replacing my `RoutingValueDictionary` `querystring` parameter by the value sent to a `javascript` function

When building a grid, its columns are generated using template.
For each column generated, I return a url:

`columns.Bound(c => c.ItemId).Title("Item #").Width("150px").Locked(true).Lockable(false).ClientTemplate("#=showDetails(data.ItemId)#");`

Then, I'm using a function where I build the `url` using `@Url.Action()`:

```
function showDetails(data) {

    var ItemDetailsUrl = "@Url.Action("Index", "ItemDetail", new 
    System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { id = "data"  }), null, Request.Url.Host)".replace("data", data);
    var returnText = "<a target='_blank' href='" + itemDetailsUrl + "'>" + data + "</a>";

    return returnText;
}
```

The way I did that, works fine. But I'm not sure if that is an efficient though.
Is there any other ways to do it?

Comment: `var ItemDetailsUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "ItemDetail")' + '/' + data;` is all you need

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I tried that way before and I get the `/ItemDetail/{data}/` as URL, my action method was not appended for some reason. Then I found that I needed to add another RouteMap for `IetmDetail` controller, however, the manager did not want to modify the routing file. So, I had to come up with another solution